# Django Union of ManyToMany Model Querysets

Tags: python, django, django-models

Here's a basic many to many relationship model:

```
from django.db import models                                                                     

class ManyToManyModel(models.Model):                                                             
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)                                                       

class MainModel(models.Model):                                                                   
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)                                                       
    many_to_many_ref = models.ManyToManyField(ManyToManyModel)
```

I create instances of these models as follows, tying the `ManyToManyModel` instances to `MainModel` instances:

```
from app1.models import ManyToManyModel, MainModel
m2m1 = ManyToManyModel(name='Number 1')
m2m1.save()
m2m2 = ManyToManyModel(name='Number 2') 
m2m2.save()
m2m3 = ManyToManyModel(name='Number 3') 
m2m3.save()
m2m4 = ManyToManyModel(name='Number 4') 
m2m4.save()

mm1 = MainModel(name='Main 1') 
mm1.save()
mm1.many_to_many_ref.add(m2m1)
mm1.save()

mm2 = MainModel(name='Main 2') 
mm2.save()
mm2.many_to_many_ref.add(m2m1)
mm2.many_to_many_ref.add(m2m2)
mm2.many_to_many_ref.add(m2m3)
mm2.save()

mm3 = MainModel(name='Main 3') 
mm3.save()
mm3.many_to_many_ref.add(m2m4)
mm3.save()
```

Now, I want to get a Queryset of ALL `ManyToManyModel`s associated with all `MainModel` objects constructed. There may be a better way to do this, but this example uses `union` (new in django 1.11):

```
for mm in MainModel.objects.all():
    try:
        m2m_union = m2m_union.union(mm.many_to_many_ref.all())
    except NameError:
        m2m_union = mm.many_to_many_ref.all()
```

Now, the `m2m_union` contains four entries in its QuerySet, but let's filter out to one that I care about, e.g. this query should only return `ManyToManyModel` with `name='Number 1'`:

```
m2m_union.get(name__endswith='1')
```

This returns the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File ".../lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 384, in get
    (self.model._meta.object_name, num)
app1.models.MultipleObjectsReturned: get() returned more than one ManyToManyModel -- it returned 4!
```

However, if I query the `ManyToManyModel` instances directly and try to get the object that way, it works:

```
ManyToManyModel.objects.all().get(name__endswith='1')
```

Why does the QuerySet created by the iterative `union` not behave the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't filter after doing the `union`. As stated [in the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.union):

> ... only LIMIT, OFFSET, COUNT(*), and ORDER BY (i.e. slicing, count(),
>   and order_by()) are allowed on the resulting QuerySet. Further,
>   databases place restrictions on what operations are allowed in the
>   combined queries. For example, most databases don’t allow LIMIT or
>   OFFSET in the combined queries.

In your case you could actually get the object you want with:

```
m2m_union.order_by('name').first()
```

But of course that's not what you want, you would filter on the desired field before making the union.